# error while deploying my netbeans project on the server

Tags: web-services, tomcat, netbeans, web-deployment

i have a netbeans project which contains 4 Restful web services ! 
i did deploy it on the server but when i open my url (IpAdress/my_deployed_war_file_name) it show me this error :

`HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Resteasy threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mytest/testws/services/Service : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.mytest.testws.services.Service)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2822)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap.processScannedResources(ConfigurationBootstrap.java:384)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap.createDeployment(ConfigurationBootstrap.java:181)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ListenerBootstrap.createDeployment(ListenerBootstrap.java:32)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletBootstrap.createDeployment(ServletBootstrap.java:28)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:66)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.`

Comment: 'startup failed due to previous errors', you need to provide the lines from the log before this happened.

Comment: i did not understad you stefan ! :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.mytest.testws.services.Service)
```

That means you have compiled that class with a different (higher) Java version than your Tomcat supports. As I can see you are using Tomcat 6.0.35, therefore you need to compile your service with JDK 5 (or lower). Here is a table showing you [which Tomcat versions support which Java version](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

In Netbeans click 'Tools' -> 'Java Platforms' and define a JDK 5 or update Tomcat to a higher version.